# Nuxt/i18n: how to change head meta description?

Tags: internationalization, nuxt.js, vue-i18n, nuxt-i18n

How can I change the head meta tag `og:description` content value that is added by i18n as default?

I know I can rewrite it in every page with head function, but I'm looking for better way.

Maybe the best way is to force i18n to fill the `og:description` content value with the value of the `description` tag content value.

[image: in this picture you can see default value and i want this value to be changed]

Comment: If you want the same description on every page you but it in the head of the `nuxt.config.js` file. Or by adding a global mixin which can take a variables from an external database or if you but the data in the `data()` on every page. Personally I have a function in `methods` which I import on the pages I need it on and return the function in the head: `head() {return this.myFunction(myDescription, myTitle)}`.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @doebi 's approach I came up with the following solution to the problem.

```js
export default {
  head() {
    return this.headData
  }
  computed: {
    headData() {
      const t = this.$i18n.t
      return {
        title: t('thispages.title'),
        meta: [
          {
            hid: 'description',
            name: 'description',
            content: t('thispages.description')
          }
        ],
      }
    }
  },
  ...

}
```

And in Nuxt with composition API we can utilize `useMeta`

```js
export default {
  setup(){
    const 
      { t } = useI18n() // from 'vue-i18n'

    useMeta({ // from '@nuxtjs/composition-api
      title: t('thispages.title'),
      meta: [
        {
          hid: 'description',
          name: 'description',
          content: t('thispages.description')
        }
      ]
    })
  },
  ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and couldn't find a fancy methods out of the box. So I came up with this solution:

```js
export default {

  computed: {
    locale() {
      return this.$i18n.localeProperties.code;
    }
  },

  head() {
    const heads = {
      'en': {
        title: 'English Title',
        meta: [
          {
            hid: 'description',
            name: 'description',
            content: 'Home page description'
          }
        ],
      },
      'de': {
        title: 'Deutscher Titel',
        meta: [
          {
            hid: 'description',
            name: 'description',
            content: 'Home page description'
          }
        ],
      }
    };
    return heads[this.locale];
  }

}
```

Create an object `heads`for all the languages you want to support and let the head function return the proper one based on the `locale` variable. I used a computed property, because it is also used in the template.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `definePageMeta` function provided by Nuxt 3 to define page-specific metadata, including Open Graph tags. The `useI18n` composable from `nuxt-i18n` can be used to access the localized strings.

First, ensure that you have set up your i18n plugin correctly and that you have the translations for your descriptions ready in your locale files 145.

Here is an example of how you would use `definePageMeta` in your page component to set the `og:description` meta tag:

```html
<script setup>
import { definePageMeta } from '#imports'
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n'

const { t } = useI18n()

definePageMeta({
  head: {
    meta: [
      {
        hid: 'og:description',
        property: 'og:description',
        content: t('descriptionKey') // Replace 'descriptionKey' with your actual i18n key
      }
    ]
  }
})
</script>
```

For a more complete `<head>` solution I highly suggest [`unhead`](https://unhead.unjs.io/), for your case there's a [`useSeoMeta`](https://unhead.unjs.io/usage/composables/use-seo-meta) composable. This library has a `nuxt`integration guide too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the same value for `og:description` on every page, you can set it in `nuxt.config.js` or in `/layout/default.vue`. Unless you specify a new value in `/pages/yourPage.vue` this will make the tag value the same on every page.

In the meta of you head in `nuxt.config.js` add the following:

```
export default {
  head: {
    meta: [
      { hid: 'og:description', property: 'og:description' content: 'My own description' },
    ],
  }
}
```

You can do the same with `og:title`, etc.